# Can you play new games with an old PSP?

Tags: psp

I am looking at buying a first generation PlayStation Portable.  I was wondering if anyone knows if you can play the newer generation games in the first generation PSP?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can play any PSP game on the first gen PSP, the only thing that matters here is the firmware. If you keep that up-to-date, you should have no problem whatsoever.